# iPhone - How do I pull up ios5's built-in dictionary from within an app

Tags: objective-c, ios

ios5 has a built in dictionary. How can I pull it up from within my app?  For example, if there was a button, and when they click it, it pulls up a random word from the dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609158/how-can-i-retrieve-random-words-from-the-iphones-dictionary ?

Comment: @anon ios5 has a new built in dictionary. http://itunes.apple.com/app/id473493861 is an example of an app that uses it. The dictionary slides down from the top and overlays the app.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` (bit of a mouthfull!)

e.g.:

```
UIReferenceLibraryViewController *dictController = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:word];
[self presentModalViewController:dictController animated:YES];
```

where "word" is the word you want to lookup.