# How to store / use a complete English Dictionary in an iOS app?

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary

I've read that since iOS5, devs could have access to the built in dictionary of words like the spell checker uses (though im not sure this is a "complete" dictionary) and Ive seen Mac OSC examples of getting a definition for a given word with UIReferenceLibraryViewController

Im looking to have access to a full English dictionary in a project im working on (random words), but I'm unsure as to whether this is something that can be done using iOS's built in dictionary (and if so, how?) or bundled with the app somehow  (XML) or just using a mySQL database.

Id prefer to figure out how to do this without have to access a db on the web though if at all possible.

To be clear, i'm asking for help on how to best approach having access to a full dictionary of real words - for example, user touches a UIButton and any one of the 171,476 (source: oxford dictionary site) english words appears in a UILabel randomly.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that devs have access to the built in dictionary?  Not that I don't think it is true, I'm just curious

Comment: If the phone already comes with a dictionary, what's the point of building your own if you don't want to use web services to extend your definitions to more sites?

Comment: You can use the built-in dictionary to show a definition of a given word and to check whether a word has a definition in the dictionary, but you can't pick a random word from it or list all the words that it contains.

Comment: You have access to the built-in *spell-checker* (`UITextChecker`). I'm not aware of any class that provides access to the dictionary database.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` can be used to show definitions in a system-provided UI, and it has the class method `dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599160/iphone-how-do-i-pull-up-ios5s-built-in-dictionary-from-within-an-app) was one question i found that piqued my interest, but i too never found any clarity in Apples Dev Docs, at least for what i'm looking for.

Comment: @omz Yes, but it does not have the ability to return the definition of a word as a string or other data type, which the question seems to be looking for as its answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS dictionary API is only suitable for looking for word definitions, not for generating random words. For your purpose, you can buy the license of a third party library like Lexicontext (http://www.lexicontext.com), or bundle your own dictionary in a SQLite database. You could use WordNet (http://wnsql.sourceforge.net/) as your database source.

Comment: thanks dan, for the resources as well.  I'm going to use the SQLite db route, i really appreciate the help.